# Otimização no sql

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Considerando essas duas tabelas no banco de dados:

Tabela Produto:

```
| id  | nome      |
|-----|-----------|
| aaa | Produto A |
| bbb | Produto B |
| ccc | Produto C |
```

Tabela Atributos:

```
| id_produto | atributo | valor   |
|------------|----------|---------|
| aaa        | cor      | azul    |
| aaa        | tamanho  | M       |
| bbb        | cor      | preto   |
| bbb        | tamanho  | P       |
| ccc        | cor      | amarelo |
| ccc        | tamanho  | G       |
```

e a seguinte consulta SQL:

```
select
    p.nome,
    c.valor,
    t.valor
from
    Produto p,
    Atributos c,
    Atributos t
where
    p.id = c.id_produto and
    p.id = t.id_produto and
    c.atributo = 'cor' and
    t.atributo = 'tamanho'
```

Há alguma forma de fazer esse select sem duplicar a tabela atributos?

### Edit #1

Resultado:

```
| nome      | cor     | Tamanho |
|-----------|---------|---------|
| Produto A | azul    | M       |
| Produto B | preto   | P       |
| Produto C | amarelo | G       |
```

Observação: Não posso alterar a estrutura das tabelas, o banco real tem diversos tipos de atributos diferentes (são gerados dinamicamente) e milhares de registros.

Comment: Você está usando letras na `primary_key`?

Comment: Está dando lentidão?

Comment: Todos os dados são recebidos via integração, e sim, pode ter letras na primary key. o ponto não é a estrutura do banco, mas sim como o select é feito

Comment: Acredito que o que você quer é transpor o resultado da tabela `atributos` para cada ocorrência do `produto`. Pesquisa sobre `pivot`

Comment: Como eu obteria esse resultado usando pivot?

Comment: Postei como resposta baseado no seu modelo de exemplo. Aplica lá no seu cenário real e confere se a molhora de performance se reflete. Acredito que sim, porque para cada 'atributo' que você quisesse incluir no resultado você teria que gerar um produto cartesiano na tabela `atributos` se seguir a abordagem atual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É bom você verificar se compensa com relação à performance para o seu caso real, mas para o exemplo apresentado seria o seguinte:

```
SELECT NOME,
       COR,
       TAMANHO
FROM (
    SELECT 
        P.NOME AS NOME,
        A.ATRIBUTO AS ATRIBUTO ,
        A.VALOR AS VALOR
    FROM PRODUTO P
        JOIN ATRIBUTOS A ON A.ID_PRODUTO = P.ID_PRODUTO ) AS FONTE 
        PIVOT ( MIN(VALOR) FOR ATRIBUTO IN (COR, TAMANHO)) AS PVT
```

No caso do seu snipet de exemplo, executando as consultas nas duas abordagens a primeira (cruzando a tabela) custa **71%** enquanto a segunda forma, **29%**, ou seja, **aproximadamente 1 /3 do esforço**. Acredito que o mesmo se reflita para você no caso real, mas não deixe de mensurar.

Answer (score 0):

Não, pois são duas linhas diferentes sendo buscadas.
A melhor solução aqui seria você refazer as tabelas, evitando a comparação de 
strings dos atributos (o que mesmo com as strings indexadas, seria mais lento do que a declaração do atributo direto no tipo):

Tabela Produto:

```
| id  | nome      |
|-----|-----------|
| aaa | Produto A |
| bbb | Produto B |
| ccc | Produto C |
```

Tabela Atributos:

```
| id_produto | tamanho | cor     |
|------------|---------|---------|
| aaa        | M       | azul    |
| bbb        | P       | preto   |
| ccc        | G       | amarelo |
```

Comment: Não posso alterar a estrutura do banco, esses atributos são gerados dinamicamente, e podem não ser os mesmos para diferentes produtos

Comment: Qualquer outra solução também fará a tabela aparecer 2x na consulta. Mas o mais importante é: Qual o principal motivo por trás disso? Tem como adicionar um `EXPLAIN` para ver se existe um motivo real de otimização?

Comment: O custo dessa consulta está em 76364714160, estou usando uma representação mais simplificada aqui

Comment: Então você precisa remodelar o seu banco de dados, seja adicionando um novo índice ou pedindo o remodelamento dele inteiro. Otimizações em query no geral devem ser feitas em casos bem específicos - e como nesse caso está procurando no BD inteiro, não há nada que vc possa fazer

Answer (score 0):

Podes fazer fazer uma cláusula with da atributos por id e casa um dos atributos da tabela atributo e depois cruzar com a produto. 
 Utiliza o hint de performance " Materialize" para otimizar a performance. Podes ativar o parelismo também.

Assim não duplicas informações.
Se for preciso tento explicar melhor

Comment: Seria interessante você incluir a query mencionada em sua resposta

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo com Pivot, veja se serve para seu caso:

**Script Pivot:**

```
SELECT 
    p.nome,
    p.cor,
    p.tamanho

FROM 
    (
    select
        p.nome, 
        a.atributo,
        a.valor
    from #produto p
    inner join #atributos a on p.id = a.id_produto
    group by p.nome, a.atributo, a.valor
    ) as x
 PIVOT (max(valor) 
FOR atributo IN ([cor],[tamanho]))P
ORDER BY 1;
```

**Resultado**

```
**nome | cor | tamanho**

Produto A | azul |  M

Produto B | preto | P

Produto C | amarelo |   G
```

**Script para criação do banco (SQL Server):**

```
create table #produto(
    id varchar(50) primary key,
    nome varchar(50)
);

create table #atributos(
    id_produto varchar(50) references #produto(id),
    atributo varchar(50) not null,
    valor varchar(50) not null
);

insert into #produto values
('aaa', 'Produto A'),
('bbb', 'Produto B'),
('ccc', 'Produto C')

insert into #atributos values
('aaa', 'cor', 'azul'),
('aaa', 'tamanho', 'M'),
('bbb', 'cor', 'preto'),
('bbb', 'tamanho', 'P'),
('ccc', 'cor', 'amarelo'),
('ccc', 'tamanho', 'G')
```